# Prove $0 \leq 1 -\cos(x) \leq x^2/2$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Can someone help me prove that $0 \leq 1 -\cos(x) \leq x^2/2$

The hint from the book, was that I could assume that $ x \in (0, PI/2), $ then I could use Pythagoras' to realise that $ |QP| = \sqrt(2 -2cosx)$ and use that the line QP must be shorter than the arc lenght between the two points. And from there I can use the same arguemnt for $ x \in (Pi/2, PI)$. But I don't quite understand what to do.

[image]

Comment: What can you use?

Comment: Can you use Taylor series? If not, first consider that for angles in the 1st quadrant, $\sin x \le x \le \tan x$

Comment: The hint from the book, was that I could assume that $ x \in (0, PI/2), $ then I could use Pythagoras' to realise that $ |QP| = \sqrt(2 -2cosx)$ and use that the line QP must be shorter than the arc lenght between the two points. And from there I can use the same arguemnt for $ x \in (Pi/2, PI)$. But I don't quite understand what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what you have written in comments about your textbooks idea: consider the unit circle with center at $O$ and points $P$ and $Q$ on the circle such that $\angle POQ=x$. Let us assume that $x \in (0, \pi/2)$. 
[image]

Consider the $\triangle POQ$, let $OM$ be the perpendicular from $O$ onto the line $PQ$. In $\triangle OMP$, we have 
$$\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{MP}{OP}=\frac{MP}{1}=MP.$$
Thus the segment $PQ=2MP=2\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$.

Since the arc $PQ$ is greater than or equal to the line segment $PQ$, therefore we have 
$$\text{segment }PQ = 2\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \leq x=\text{arc }PQ.$$
This implies
\begin{align*}
 2\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) &\leq x\\
2\sin^2 \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) &\leq \frac{x^2}{2}\\
1-\cos x & \leq \frac{x^2}{2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

$\cos x\le1$ can be taken for granted. Then if we integrate twice from $0$ to $x$,

$$\int_0^x\cos x\,dx=\sin x\le x,$$

$$\int_0^x\sin x\,dx=1-\cos x\le\frac{x^2}2.$$

---

Note that we can continue forever

$$\int_0^x(1-\cos x)\,dx=x-\sin x\le\frac{x^3}6,$$

$$\int_0^x(x-\sin x)\,dx=-1+\frac{x^2}2+\cos x\le\frac{x^4}{24},$$

$$\cdots$$

which leads us to the Taylor development.

---

Successive upper and lower polynomial bounds of the cosine:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

The inequality $\cos(x)\leq 1$, is trivial because  $\cos(x)\leq \sqrt{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}=1$.

For the second one let $f(x):=x^2/2-1 +\cos(x)$. We have to show that $f(x)\geq 0$. Since $f(-x)=f(x)$, it suffices to consider the case when $x\ge 0$. Now
$$f'(x)=x-\sin(x)\quad\text{and}\quad f''(x)=1-\cos(x)\geq 0$$
which means that $f'(x)$ is increasing and $f'(x)\geq f'(0)=0$. Hence also $f$ is increasing for $x\geq 0$, that is $f(x)\geq f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Because of symmetry it suffices to consider non-negative values of $x$.
$$1-\cos(x)=\int_0^x\sin(y)\,{\rm d}y\leq\int_0^xy\,{\rm d}y=x^2/2.$$

Comment: You are silently using $y\le\sin y$ without justification.

Comment: I like this method ! (+1)  @YvesDaoust : Just a draw is enough to justify that $|\sin(y)|\leq |y|$ (and not the inverse inequality as you wrote). It's moreover a very very known inequality...

Comment: @idm: "It's moreover a very very know inequality" is a very poor argument. Because $\cos x\ge 1-x^2/2$ is also a very very known inequality. And a draw is *never* a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos(x)\leq 1$, one inequality follow. For the other one

**Method 1**

$$1-\cos(x)=\cos(0)-\cos(x)=2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=2\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2\leq \frac{x^2}{2},$$

where the last inequality come from the fact that $|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$ for all $x$.

**Method 2**

For all $x$, there is $c_x\in ]0,x[$ s.t. $$1-\cos(x)=\cos(c_x)\frac{x^2}{2}\leq \frac{x^2}{2}.$$